# How to correctly instantiate a log4j Logger object into my class?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am working on a simple Java command line and I need to insert **log4j** into my application, so I am following this tutorial:

http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/07/log4j-tutorial-adding-log4j-logging-to-your-project/

So I have done the following step:

1. I put the log4j jar file into the library of my project.
2. I put the log4j.properties into a config package and I configured it with this minimal configuration:

   ```
   #define the console appender
   log4j.appender.consoleAppender = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

   # now define the layout for the appender
   log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
   log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

   # now map our console appender as a root logger, means all log messages will go to this appender
   log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, consoleAppender
   ```

   So this configuration say that the output have to be printed into the console and I associate the **DEBUG** mode.
3. Now the tutorial say that:

   > In any of your Java file, add the below lines, in order to start
   >   logging.

   And show this example code:

   ```
   private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyclassName.class);
   logger.debug("this is a sample log message.");
   ```

   Ok, I have not understand what exatly I have to do to instantiate the `Logger` into my class.

   My class is named `Mailer` so have I to do something like:

   ```
   private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Mailer.class);
   ```

   Or what? What exactly have I to do?

**EDIT 1:** My class is something like:

```
public class Mailer {

    private static final org.apache.log4j.Logger logger = new Logger(Mailer.class);
    ...................................
    ...................................
    ...................................
}
```

The problem is that IntelliJ show me an error on the **Logger(Mailer.class);** and say to me: **Logger(java.Lang.String) has protected access in 'org.apache.log4j.Logger'**

Why? How can I solve this issue?

Tnx

Comment: Yes that's it (you could also make it final) - does it not work?

Comment: @RaviThapliyal edited inserting the error at the end of my original post

Comment: @assylias edited inserting the error at the end of my original post

Comment: You have to use the factory method: Logger.getLogger() You don't instantiate the  Logger class directly.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal ok but what have I to use as input parameter of the getLogger() method?

Comment: Why aren't you using the `private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Mailer.class);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

and then in your code you write for example:

```
logger.debug("Your message);
....
logger.error("Somehting crahsed",e);...
```

Comment: @AndreaNobili use `Logger.getLogger(Mailer.class)` instead of `new Logger(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use LogManager

Checkout this link-

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager.html#getLogger()

So for your code the change would be something like this-

```
     private static final org.apache.log4j.Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Mailer.class);
     logger.debug("Its debugging");
```